# Throwing or re-throwing an exception?

Tags: java, exception

If I put in the catch clause:

```
...
catch(Exception e)
{
    throw new Exception("msg", e); 
}
```

Am I throwing or re-throwing the e exception?

So is correct to say that the throw clause used
into a catch is **re-throwing** an exception while using it
into a try block or elsewhere is **throwing** an exception?

Ultimately when or where thow **throw** an exception and when or where **re-throw** an exception?

Thanks.

Comment: You're throwing a new exception here, which wraps the actual exception. I would classify re-throwing as `throw e`.

Comment: You should probably catch something less generic than Exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You throw an exception the first time.

```
throw new Exception();
```

You re-throw a caught exception

```
} catch (Exception e) {
   // do something
   throw e;
}
```

You wrap an exception by throwing a different exception which contains that exception.

```
} catch (Exception e) {
   // do something
   throw new Exception(e);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would call that throwing an exception.

This is re-throwing an exception:

```
...
catch(Exception e)
{
    throw e;
}
```

I would throw a new exception if I want to wrap several exceptions into one, or if I want to add new information. If not, I think it's better to re-throw it.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/07/rethrowing-exceptions.html

This link should help you make the decision of when to rethrow the exception.

Usually, the catch should be able to handle the exception itself, but if it cannot, then I'd advise re-throwing the exception. Another thing to take notice of is where the catch is (for example in a controller vs a model, you usually want the catch in a controller action so you can handle it in the view. However, exceptions happen in the model frequently)

Answer (score 0):

To answer the last question:

Throw a new exception if doing so adds value. For example, it's common to wrap up underlying exceptions in application-specific exceptions for consumption in higher layers. These should almost always be chained to preserve the original exception's information.

IMO re-throwing is usually not a great idea, because a layer of context will be removed from the exception chain/stack trace. OTOH, if you genuinely can't do anything with it, re-throwing may make the most sense. In that case, I generally indicate the method `throws` and don't do local exception handling unless necessary for cleanup of local resources/etc.

Answer (score 0):

If certain prerequisites are not met to execute a business condition we will throw custom exceptions, for example if balance in account is 0, can't debit, you will throw NotSufficientAmountException.

re-throw is for different purposes, one, to let caller know that something wrong happend, two, pass the stacktrace to caller with more details on which line of code error occured etc.,

Answer (score 0):

Your question is: "Am I throwing or re-throwing the e exception?"

You are neither throwing or re-throwing the e exception
You are throwing a new Exception with some new message. 
The original e exception (the exception that was caught) is the reason why you threw the new exception and consequently it will appear in the causedBy of the newly thrown exception.

oh boy.